# How do I increase the coin income per tap?

Tags: curiosity

In his [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxZnVwxKSLM) of the [Curiosity](http://www.22cans.com/) app, Peter Molyneux said that there are ways (based of rhythm, maybe?) to increase the amount of coins you earn, per tap.

Also, in the "info screen" from the Curiosity app, it is said that

> there are skill mechanics that you will need to master

---

Tapping one cube brings one coin, basically.

What are the ways to increase that amount? Are there combo mechanics, rhythm-based scoring?

Comment: ["We're going to be changing some rules; our first rule change will probably come next week, and that'll be really exciting. All of this exciting stuff is yet to be."](http://gamasutra.com/view/news/181114/Not_even_Apple_knows_whats_inside_Curiositys_cube.php) - So there's probably going to be some changes to these answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So far I've discovered:

**Combo multipliers**: you get a multiplier increasing, as long as you tap **without missing**, and you tap one new block in the next **2 seconds** after tapping one.

So far, I don't manage to find the logic behind the actual number of cubes for the multiplier steps, but here goes for the first ones:

- 2x: 12 cubes
- 3x: 26 cubes
- 4x: 42 cubes
- 5x: 61 cubes
- etc...

**"Clear Screen Bonus"** - What it says on the tin. Clear your whole screen of cubes and you'll get some coins as a bonus.

The amount is equal to the score you earned on clearing those cubes in the first place (including the bonus from the multiplier), multiplied by 10.

Comment: After spending far too much time, I came to about the same conclusions, with more numbers for the combo. Didn't know it was proportional to the zoom level for the clean screen, though, I've just checked that, and indeed, I see it now.

Comment: I added what I found to your answer, feel free to change things from it.

Comment: Ah, found it, it's not proportional to the zoom level, it's simply multiplying the score, including multipliers, by 10. So what seemed proportional was only because of the increased combo chain.

Answer (score 2):

I just played a series and the best combo method I found without any bonuses is methodical and slow tapping to clear screens.  Large screens seem not to be worth it, as a full screen combos at 8,000 maybe at 18x multiplier, but 6 cubes value at 600-900 at the same range.  small screens that are quick clears are more desirable once you have a large multiplyer I think.  Easier to track each tap as well with more white space if they are small groupings.  I played at the max zoom for this usually just because I didn't want to risk losing the combo, and it because it did seem to have good returns.  Further zooms might be better once you have apick.

watch out for the FB or tool icon to pop up as it will kill your combo timer.

*edit - apparently on the twitter account they suggest the best way to get rid of the FB icon is to log into facebook.... clever.

I got 200,000 coins in about 5-10 minutes by going carefully into a semi-cleared section and screen clearing and not missing a combo.  my total tap meter was at about 17,000 and during that stretch I got 200,000 coins.  I imagine that if I could buy the chisel at 300,000 that my screen clear time would go much faster and thus my multiplier would add up faster on the clear combo.  I'd guess the 25 square tool would super bump the screen clear.

I think the best way to go is to get the pick tools and clear quickly while maximizing combos so that you can afford the tool the next time + coin gain.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it's better to take the time to tap the whole screen without missing a cube, and under the 2 seconds between each cube, for a much higher score, than some frenzy with tapping in every direction, with all fingers. Although if you manage to find a place without blanks, unzooming then tapping with all fingers can give good results for a start, as the smallness of the cubes makes it that your finger will almost always touch something, until you dig bigger holes.

Answer (score 1):

Use iPad with large Screen:

1. Combo + Clear Screen until 1 Mil.
2. Combo + Clear Screen + Iron chisel

In the 7 Min with the chisel you make around 1.5 - 2.5 Mil. (Net: 05. - 1.5 Mil)

But be careful: coins are getting lost at the moment